# Missing client.QueryManager.refetchQueryByName

Tags: apollo-client

I use client.QueryManager.refetchQueryByName to refetch query and update view.

```
client.queryManager.fatchQuery('GetCalendarEvents')
```

But, current apollo-client is missing the method.

How can I achieve the same thing in current version.

apollo-client version : 2.6.3